# What happens in GrabCut Algorithm

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing

I want to know the what actually happnens in the following code.

```
cv::Rect rectangle(x,y,width,height);

    cv::Mat result; 
    cv::Mat bgModel,fgModel;


    cv::grabCut(image,  
                    result,  
                    rectangle,
                    bgModel,fgModel, 
                    1,       
                    cv::GC_INIT_WITH_RECT);


    cv::compare(result,cv::GC_PR_FGD,result,cv::CMP_EQ);

    // Generate output image
    cv::Mat foreground(image.size(),CV_8UC3,cv::Scalar(255,255,255));
    image.copyTo(foreground,result);
```

According to my knowledge when we define the rectangle outside the rectangle will be consider as the known background and the inside as the unknown foreground.

Then `bgmodel` and `fgmodel` are Gausian mixed models which keeps the foreground and background pixels separately.

The parameter we are passing as 1 means, we are asking to divide the pixels to separate pixels process to run only once.

what i can't understand is

```
cv::compare(result,cv::GC_PR_FGD,result,cv::CMP_EQ);
```

What actually happens in the above method.

If anyone could explain, that would be a great help.
thanx.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found [this book](http://books.google.ru/books?id=OC7jc8zWjlkC&pg=PT100&lpg=PT100&dq=cv%3a%3acompare%28result,cv%3a%3aGC_PR_FGD,result,cv%3a%3aCMP_EQ%29;&source=bl&ots=CctoPWoLBm&sig=rnJOG8nbM0vXaMRWex7HCY4poeM&hl=ru&sa=X&ei=AgmMUsiAN4mU4ASxh4CoCg&ved=0CEcQ6AEwAw#v=onepage&q=cv%3a%3acompare%28result,cv%3a%3aGC_PR_FGD,result,cv%3a%3aCMP_EQ%29;&f=true) which tells that this code compares values of pixels in `result` to `GC_PR_FGD` value. Those that are equal it doesn't touch, all the other pixels it deletes. Here's a citation from there:

> The input/output segmentation image can have one of the four values:
>
> - cv::GC_BGD, for pixels certainly belonging to the background (for example, pixels outside the rectangle in our example)
> - cv::GC_FGD, for pixels certainly belonging to the foreground (none in our example)
> - cv::GC_PR_BGD, for pixels probably belonging to the background
> - cv::GC_PR_FGD for pixels probably belonging to the foreground (that is the initial value for the pixels inside the rectangle in our
>     example).
>
> We get a binary image of the segmentation by extracting the pixels
>   having a value equal to cv::GC_PR_FGD:
>
> ```
> // Get the pixels marked as likely foreground
> cv::compare(result,cv::GC_PR_FGD,result,cv::CMP_EQ);
> // Generate output image
> cv::Mat foreground(image.size(),CV_8UC3,
>                 cv::Scalar(255,255,255));
> image.copyTo(foreground, // bg pixels are not copied
>           result);
> ```

Comment: Actually this code works well. Here 'result' is input array.And i think 'cv::GC_PR_FGD' mask and the again the output image will be the result.

Comment: @kevin Updated. Got confused with non-strict typing of function arguments.